# Can we design multiplexer that input -vdc?

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, analog-switch

I'm research about signal 2 state(+V ,-V) .So I have a question about multiplexer.I know that multiplexer is Digital circuit then input and output must be only 0 or 1
But in my research i need Analog circuit multiplexer like pic.1

[image]

```
pic.1
```

from pic.1 ''321'' is control switch to choose input +Vt or -Vt

If switch is 1 output is +Vt .
If switch is 0 output is -Vt

I do not sure that call multiplexer but i need circuit like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an analog multiplexer. There are a few members of the 4000 series and  74HC4000 series which do this (eg. [74HC4053](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4053.pdf)). Most analog switch members will allow a +/-5V or +/-3V supplies and will level shift the input so they can be controlled with a 5V/0 or 3V/0 control signal respectively.

You can also find a plethora of higher performance analog switches such as [this  one](https://www.vishay.com/docs/70662/dg213.pdf) which will operate from higher voltages, have better and more constant on-resistance, have built in protection, and are specified for things like charge injection and low leakage. Of course the cost will be higher.

Comment: (1) No need to go the analog way. There is the misconception that zero/false must be ground and one/true vcc. The first computers built with DTL/RTL and all that kind of technologies used other voltages to define logic values.

Comment: (2) If a logic value is to be translated to voltages outside the scope of most TTL/CMOS logic the best way is first to have some power rails with the voltage to output and pull them using resistors over an open collector/drain component as 74LS06/74LS07 are.

Comment: I disagree, but feel free to add your own answer showing how you would solve this particular problem.

Comment: When I mean digital, I mean no values in between than the agreed true and false values. Also note that I place numbers in comments to specify their order if it is too long. I don't have time to write a proper response in this moment, but I will writer later this day, more to complement than replace yours which is already good.